# SwiftUI: Spacing between List Items

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have some code that displays a list with a title and a rectangle and if the user taps on it, it navigates to a detail page.

But my code seems to have multiple problems:

1. The spacer is not working. I want the name on the left and the rectangle on the right like a spacer in a Stack would push it.
2. The background color of the rectangle is not applied. It is just black
3. If I add a navigationTitle, I see constraint errors (see below)

> (
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002438f50 'BIB_Trailing_CB_Leading' H:[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fd15fe088b0]-(6)-[_UIModernBarButton:0x7fd15fe064d0'World Clock']   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002438fa0 'CB_Trailing_Trailing' _UIModernBarButton:0x7fd15fe064d0'World Clock'.trailing <= _UIButtonBarButton:0x7fd15fe05310.trailing   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002439d10 'UINav_static_button_horiz_position' _UIModernBarButton:0x7fd15fe088b0.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x600003e04a80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600002439d60 'UINavItemContentGuide-leading' H:[_UIButtonBarButton:0x7fd15fe05310]-(0)-[UILayoutGuide:0x600003e049a0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide']   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000024350e0 'UINavItemContentGuide-trailing' UILayoutGuide:0x600003e049a0'UINavigationBarItemContentLayoutGuide'.trailing == _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fd15fd0a640.trailing   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000243a4e0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' _UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fd15fd0a640.width == 0   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000024354a0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(0)-UILayoutGuide:0x600003e04a80'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'   (active, names: '|':_UINavigationBarContentView:0x7fd15fd0a640 )>"
> )

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        
        List {
            ForEach(viewModel.cityList, id: \.name) { city in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: CityDetailView(city: city)){
                    HStack{
                        Text(city.name)
                        Spacer()
                        CustomView()
                    }
                }.frame(height: 100)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("World Clock")
    }
}

    CustomView:
        var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                Circle().frame(width: geo.size.height, height: geo.size.height)
                .background(Color.green)
            }
        }
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: please add SwiftUI code you having troubles with, like [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: and format your error text so it'll be more readable, you can do it by placing `>` at the line start

Comment: Why are you using an empty NavigationLink? Why don't use a NavigationLink instead of Hstack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your spacer doesn't work because there's `NavigationLink` in the `HStack` which took all the space: it has bigger priority than `Spacer`.

If you wanna use `NavigationLink` with `EmptyView`, it should be placed in a `ZStack` with nearby view, but in this case you can simply place content of your cell inside `NavigationLink` `label`.

`Rectangle` is not a view but a `Shape`, and as with any other `Shape` its color should be set with `foregroundColor`, not with `background`.

`GeometryReader` always takes all available space, unless you're adding size modifiers to it. It cannot wrap around content by itself. So you can use following trick: add `onAppear` for an item inside `GeometryReader` and pass `width` to state variable, which will then add width modifier to `GeometryReader`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = CityListViewModel()

    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.cityList, id: \.name) { city in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text(city.name)){
                        HStack{
                            Text(city.name)
                            Spacer()
                            CustomView()
                        }
                    }.frame(height: 100)
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("World Clock")
        }
    }
}

struct CustomView: View {
    @State
    var width: CGFloat?
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            Circle().frame(width: geo.size.height, height: geo.size.height)
                .background(Color.green)
                .onAppear {
                    width = geo.size.height
                }
        }.frame(width: width)
    }
}
```

If you see some `NSLayoutConstraint` broken which you didn't create, like when using SwiftUI, you can ignore it: it's not your bug.

Comment: You are right. With Shapes this is working. But in my project I have a View and this view is sized with a Geometry Reader. Let me update my question.

Comment: @netshark1000 is this a real code or still far from real? why can't you add `.frame(width: 100, height: 100)` to circle instead of `GeometryReader`? It's greedy just like `NavigationLink` and takes all available space too. You have `Spacer` and `GeometryReader`, how do you expect `GeometryReader` to calculate available height? Can't you place GeometryReader under HStack?

Comment: This is a simplified example. Instead of the Circle I have other Views that need to adjust it's size dependent on the available space. But I can reproduce it with this simple example of a circle.

Comment: @netshark1000 I've updated my answer, check out how you can trick `GeometryReader` to not fill all space